# AWS key: could not connect to Ubuntu 22.04.4 using the same key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Launched an EC2 instance. The same AWS key could not connect to the new Ubuntu 22.04.4 using PUTTY. SSH port 22.

```
error: could not agree on host key algorithms(...)
```

The same AWS key can connect to other Ubuntu 20.04.4 instances.

### UPDATE

Create a new key, and launched a new instance Ubuntu 22.04 using the new key. Same error. Could not connect to the instance.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because Ubuntu 22.04 does not use RSA authentication keys. (CentOS9 is the same.)
Note: I know RSA authentication is disabled in openssh version 8.9 and later.

There are two workarounds.

1. Add the following to Userdata when creating EC2.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

2. Generate ED25519 type key from SSH key piar to create EC2